# UseEffect with Async function

Tags: reactjs, webpack, axios

I'm having a problem with my get request function using Axios. whenever its got called, the get function always runs twice. I don't know what the problem is here. I have tried removing React.Strictmode tag but nothing changed. I started to think the webpack dev server is the problem here.
Here is my code :

1. my get Request function :

```
export default async function useSendResquest(url, handler) {
  var Response;
  Response = await axios.get(url).then((response) => {
    return response.data;
  });
  return handler(Response);
}
```

2. My UseEffect Call :

```
useEffect(() => {
  useSendResquest(
    "http://localhost:8080/api/control?name=rgbLed&status",
    (Response) => {
      setLightState(Response);
    }
  );
  console.log("hi");
}, []);
```

3. Network activity :

[image]

4. My Console Log :
   [image]

does anyone have any clue?

Thank you all

Comment: Are you sure setLightState does not say "Hi" too?

Comment: i double check and it was not

Comment: Not related to the question but try to avoid using `var` use `let` instead

Comment: Can you try replacing the `var` with `let` or even better `const`? It might be unrelated, above all it's a good practice, but I do have a sneaking suspicion given it exists in global scope the response actually gets instantiated twice, first as the global initialization of var and then whatever gets passed by the return of the `axios` call, hence causing component to re-mount with updated state and `useEffect` running twice.

Comment: @SamuelHulla it's kind of weird tho, though I have tried your solution, and nothing changed. And I even try to comment   the useSendResquest, the result is still the same

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem with why my app kept rerendering.it is because of my index.html template. The webpack compiler tried to add `<script defer src="bundle.js"></script>` twice, at the top of the HTML and at the bottom of it tool. After fixing this problem in the webpack config, everything ran as it should.